# Substrings, searching lists

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list which is being filled with user-entered strings. I've already checked that the string isn't empty, and that the list doesn't contain that string.

Issue I'm having is I need to check if the user entered string is a sub-string of a stored string in the list.

```
List<string> stringlist = new List<string>();
int index = 0;
string userinput = null;

while (userinput != "end")
{
    userinput = getstring();
    if (stringlist.Contains(userinput))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Term has been stored previously.");
    }
    else
    {
        stringlist.Insert(index, userinput);
        index += 1;
    }

    foreach (string s in stringlist)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("List contains : {0}", s);
        if (s.Contains(userinput))
        {
            // something?
        }
    }
} // end of main while loop
```

So basically, if a term someone enters is "dog", if one of the other strings entered is "bigdog", it should say "dog is a substring of bigdog" or something similar. Should I be making use of a different type of loop for this?

Comment: A foreach like the above would be fine. If you are using a list and you want it a little faster use a for loop. Either way they are fine. Also when adding data to a list simply use List.Add rather than List.Insert unless you need to insert data in specific indexes. Currently your doing basically what List.Add does.

Comment: You can use of [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) to find match strings without looping around a word!  Or you can contains string by another string with [Contains method of String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)                                         reference:  http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure, this particular practice task is weirdly worded.
"If the term is a sub-string of a stored term, the stored term should be displayed". My interpretation is that when the user enters a string, the whole list is checked to see if that string is a sub-string of any stored string in the list.

Comment: do  substring checking before adding userInput to list. otherwise it always true.

Comment: What if "dog" is in list and user enters "bigdog"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize everyone's advice:

- Check for substrings before adding the entry to the list
- Use `String.Contains()` method to check for sub-strings on each item in the list
- Use the `List.Add` method rather then using memory on an `index` variable

  ```
  List<string> stringlist = new List<string>();
  string userinput = null;

  while (userinput != "end")
  {
  userinput = getstring();

  // Check for Substrings
  foreach (string s in stringlist.Where(s => s.Contains(userinput)))
  {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} is a substring of {1}", userinput, s);
  }

  // Add to the list
  if (stringlist.Contains(userinput))
  {
      Console.WriteLine(" Term has been stored previously.");
  }
  else
  {
      stringlist.Add(userinput);
  }
  } // end of main while loop
  ```

You may use the `Regex` *(Regular Expressions)* class to find matches in the list but that would still require a `foreach` loop and for a simple substring search `String.Contains` will actually outperform `Regex.IsMatch` . I also tried concatenating the list to a long string and searching there in one line of code but that is highly prone to false-positives as some separate entries may form new words when joined.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (string s in stringlist)
{
    if (s.Contains(userinput))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a substring of {1}", userinput, s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stringlist.ForEach(s =>
 {
   if (s.Contains(userinput))
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0} is a substring of {1}", userinput, s);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

More optimized way.

```
   foreach (string s in stringlist.Where(s => s.Contains(userinput)))
          {
              Console.WriteLine("{0} is a substring of {1}", userinput, s);
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stringlist.Where(s => s.Contains(userinput) || userinput.Contains(s)).ToList().ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine("Part of {0} is a substring of {1}", userinput, s));
```

You may use `ToLower()` if you want it to be case insensitive.